# How to collect international train tickets from Romania to Hungary (MÁV)

Tags: trains, tickets, romania, hungary

During my trip through Romania and Hungary I'm gonna need to get from Timișoara (Romania) to Budapest.

There are buses of course, but, conveniently, there's also a train connecting two cities, which I'd prefer to take.

However, while booking using the [train company's site](https://www.mavcsoport.hu/en) I encountered a note saying

> Please note that home printing of international tickets is not
>   possible. International tickets booked online must be collected at any
>   of the Ticket Collection Points located at railway stations in Hungary
>   before your journey. Passengers travelling without a collected ticket
>   must purchase a new ticket on board and pay penalty.

I found [a page with a list](https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/EN/jegyatvetelipontok.html) of these **Ticket Collection Points**, and, it seems, all of them are located at Hungarian stations.

Has anyone had an experience booking MÁV train tickets online traveling *from Romania*? Is there an option to pick up the online ticket at a local ticket office at the Timișoara station? Or is physically going to the station and buying a ticket (not booking online) the only way to get aboard?

Comment: Why do you insist on buying a MÁV ticket? Isn't a CFR ticket an option? (I'm not sure if that would help, I'm just curious.)

Comment: Oh, I don't insist at all, and I had tried that before. Their timetable (redirecting to reiseauskunft.bahn.de for international routes) says "No OnlineTickets possible" though. MÁV at least has an option to book this train online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Man in Seat 61 the answer is that you cannot book on-line. Your alternative is to book through one of the agencies he lists or buy at the station while you are in Romania.

https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Bucharest.htm#Bucharest_to_Budapest

Note this is Bucharest to Budapest not from Timisoara but the rules will be the same.

Comment: Thank you! And a great resource too, I wonder why I haven't stumbled upon it before